# What type of strawberry plant is this?

Tags: identification, strawberries

I grew a few strawberry plants from seed and got this one!
It looks a bit sad as it has just been repotted in a bad way.

Would this be a new type of strawberry plant, or is this normal sometimes?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you plant from seeds you are risking variety in results.

If it gives good tasting fruit does it matter much what the plant looks like?  :)

If you don't like the fruit you can pull the plant later.

Comment: Your right im going to care for it and see how it tastes